# How to save fields correctly with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating a program that saves a String from one text field and an integer from a second text field. I am trying to use NSUserDefaults, but I can't seem to get either of them to save correctly when I run the program. It crashes when I press the save button with the breakpoint while handling the NSUserDefaults. Am I doing something wrong? I skimmed through the documentation, but it didn't help. Can I even use 2 different instances of NSUserDefaults?

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    //Save stuff fropm textfields
    NSString* name = _nameText.text;
    int count = [_countText.text intValue];

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count forKey:@"count"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}


- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
    //Load stuff from NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"name"];
    _nameText.text =  loadstring;

    NSUserDefaults* defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger loadint = [defaults2 integerForKey:@"count"];
    _countText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)loadint];
}
```

Comment: You might want to *read* the documentation instead of skimming through it.

Comment: While using 2 instances of NSUserDefaults in the same scope *might* work, it is horrible practice. Use one instance of it for both storing and retrieving the information, thus synchronizing only once, and let us know if you encounter any errors.

Comment: `standardUserDefault` returns the singleton instance. `defaults` and `defaults2` are the same instances. Can you provide more detail of crash log?

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: You need an actual object pointing to the standard defaults! Add the line `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` first and call the `setObject` and `setInteger` on `defaults` instead.

Comment: @trick14 I updated the code, and there is a new crash when I run and press the button that activates the 'save' method. (here: http://i.imgur.com/alOs4kA.png) I'm sorry if I couldn't provide the correct information.

Comment: @BensonTran The image you added is not crash. It's a breakpoint you set.

Comment: @trick14 Wow that's embarrassing. Sorry, I'm only a few months into Objective-C and Xcode. Okay, seems to work now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];` in your `viewDidLoad` (and `NSUserDefaults* defaults;` in .h) and use this code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    //Save stuff fropm textfields
    NSString* name = _nameText.text;
    int count = [_countText.text intValue];

    [defaults setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [defaults setInteger:count forKey:@"count"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}


- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
    //Load stuff from NSUserDefaults
    _nameText.text =  [defaults stringForKey:@"name"];
    _countText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[defaults integerForKey:@"count"]];
}
```